# Java Spring Boot API failing to initialize

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

| Spring API with MongoDB | MQTT and HTPPS |
| --- | --- |

Hello, I am currently building a **REST API** and I need to implement HTPPS and MQTT protocols using Spring Boot and Java. For my back-end **I use MongoDB locally**, which I set up using Docker CLI. The Spring application is connected with the *application.properties* configuration file ***provided below*** in pictures. It's my first time building such a complex API and I'm using these resources (which may be the cause of my problem, not resources itself, but me taking some time getting the hang of things, i put them in comments):

I am asking for some help or guidance to how can I get rid of the start-up error of the API -*stack track provided below*-
[ambulance Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvjVd.png),[ambulanceControllerClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdMPt.png),[ambulanceRepository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7Bk.png),[ambulanceServiceImpl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeQqY.png),[ambulanceService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rRby.png),[mqttBeans-p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWs7u.png),[mqttBeans-p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Heloq.png),[mqttController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGCRC.png)

***stack trace***
in comments
I couldn't post the pom.xml file, but i don't use anything more than the guys in the tutorials use.

Hope I gave enough info. Have a nice day!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=th3uIP7D8nk

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssj0CGxv60k&list=WL&index=1&t=981s

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHKrKwI--Yw

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/e93934e4

Comment: pastebin link is for the stack trace

Comment: pom.xml
https://pastebin.pl/view/b4eacb7d